# Is it possible to hide implementation of template class?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a library "myLibrary" that depends on "Blibrary". I want the users of "myLibrary" to not know that dependency. I'm trying to hide it without luck, here is an example of what I have right now.

```
#include <game/Object.h>
#include <Blibrary/Component.hpp>   // How can I remove this library header?
                                    // forward declaring it? it's a template..

namespace myLibrary {

    template<typename T>
    struct Component: public Object, public Blibrary::Component<T>
    {
    };


    //template<typename T>
    //class Blibrary::Component<T>;    //I Tried something like that..

    //template<typename T>
    //struct Component: public Object
    //{
    //  Blibrary::Component<T> * m_impl;
    //};
}



//I want the user do this when declaring a usermade component:

#include <game/Component.h>   //<-- but without the Blibrary include dependency


class Position: public myLibrary::Component<Position>
{
    float x, y, z;
};
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is it possible to hide implementation of template class?

No, it is not. A class template must be defined completely in header files. You can only obfuscate the implementation by using multiple layers of header files and using helper class names and helper function names that are obfuscations of the highest level, user visible classes.

However, as @vsoftco noted in a comment, you can hide it if you use it only for some specific types, in which case you can do explicit instantiation, export the template and implement it in the .cpp.

Comment: You can hide it if you use it only for some specific types, in which case you can do explicit instantiation, export the template and implement it in the .cpp. Trying to use it with any other types won't link.

Answer (score 0):

A nice idea from [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869479/how-to-hide-an-implementation-helper-template) was to put the implementation classes/functions you want to "hide" into another level of namespace.

You can even separate them into a different .h file to be included at the top.

Now, of course this is incapable of really hiding them programmatically from anywhere you include the header, but it does prevent them going into the scope, and means that it would not be possible to use them without explicitly dereferencing that additional namespace.

So for example you'd have namespace `mylibrary` for your library, and something like `mylibrary::priv` or `mylibrary::impl`, for example, for the things you're "hiding".

Comment: But that doesn't prevent clients of `mylibrary::Component` from being exposed to the declarations in `<Blibrary/Component.hpp>`, which I think is the goal.  Moving the inclusion of the Blibrary component into mylibrary's namespace (or a private subspace) _might_ solve the compilation problem, but it would probably break the link.  The usual way to solve this is with the pimpl idiom, but that's not compatible with a class template.